# How can I divide two sentence including web page address?

Tags: java, string, divide

I want to divide two sentence including webpage address using Java.
For example, that is divided sentence what I want
"Hello, I want to find the best solution in stackoverflow.com. For these reason, I make a question."

I want to divide this sentence as follow.

```
"Hello, I want to find the best solution in stackoverflow.com."
"For these reason, I make a question."
```

However, using split("\.") method in java I can get

```
"Hello, I want to find the best solution in stackoverflow"
"com"
"For these reason, I make a question."
```

How can do I this problem? Please help me.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Some people wrote that to solve this write following method
split("\\.(?=\\s+)");
However, that answer was deleted. So I comment  giving appreciate the person who give me answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people wrote that to solve this write following method

split("\.(?=\s+)");

However, that answer was deleted. So I write comment giving appreciate the person who give me answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space in the split:

```
String.split("\\. ");
```